# How to fix code to display data from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I already ask similar question, When i click on `textview(header_news from firebase)`, i switch to another activity and load data from Firebase. In another activity i get the same data(1 news by id). But i want to be displayed `main_news`. I know where problem, but i dont know how to fix it. I think problem in bindviewholder becouse i dont add  `myViewHolder.main_news.setText(Mnews.get(i).getMain_news());` But i cant to add, becouse its be displayed on header news.... P.S Sorry for my english i hope you understand me.

Adapter Code:

```
    public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context Mcontext;
    ArrayList<News> Mnews;


    public NewsAdapter(Context Mcontext, ArrayList<News> Mnews)
    {
        this.Mnews = Mnews;
        this.Mcontext = Mcontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(Mcontext).inflate(R.layout.news_view, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        final News news = Mnews.get(i);
        myViewHolder.news_date.setText(Mnews.get(i).getDatenews());
        myViewHolder.news_header.setText(Mnews.get(i).getHeader_news());

        Picasso.get().load(Mnews.get(i).getImageURL()).into(myViewHolder.news_picture);

        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Mcontext, NewsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("idnews", news.getIdnews());
                Mcontext.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return Mnews.size();
   }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView news_date, news_header, main_news;
        ImageView news_picture;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            news_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_date);
            news_header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_header);
            news_picture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_picture);
        }
    }
}
```

And Activity code:

```
    public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String idnews;
    TextView main_news;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    TextView news_date;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Intent intent;
    ArrayList<News> Nlist;
    NewsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        main_news = findViewById(R.id.main_news);
        intent = getIntent();
        idnews = intent.getStringExtra("idnews");

        Nlist = new ArrayList<News>();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("News").child(idnews);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Nlist.clear();
                News news = dataSnapshot.getValue(News.class);
                main_news.setText(news.getNews_main());
                Nlist.add(news);

                adapter = new NewsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), Nlist);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(NewsActivity.this, "Что то не так", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[My database struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jma2T.png)

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: If you add that line of code, what is happening?

Comment: I get no errors. It simply displays the information that was contained in the previous activity. If i add this line.

Comment: If I add this line, then along with the news headline, the main news item will also be displayed. And I need that in 1 activity only the news heading and the date were displayed. And in the next activity the main news was displayed.